# BigQuery - copy a query into a new table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I wrote a query for one of my Big Query table called `historical` and I would like to copy the result of this query into a new Big Query table called `historical_recent`. I have difficulties to figure out how to do this operation with Python. Right now, I am able to execute my query and get the expected result:

```
    SELECT * FROM gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical WHERE (date BETWEEN '2015-11-05 00:00:00' AND '
2015-11-07 23:00:00')
```

I am also able to copy a my Big Query table without making any changes with this script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
job = client.copy_table(
    'gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical',
    'gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical_copy')
```

How can I combine both using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python to save your query result.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

# Target table to save results
table_id = "gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical_recent"

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    allow_large_results=True,
    destination=table_id,
    use_legacy_sql=True
)

sql = """
   SELECT * FROM gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical 
   WHERE (date BETWEEN '2015-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-07 23:00:00')
"""

query = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
query.result()

print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

This example is based on the Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#sql).

Answer (score 2):

You can use INSERT statement as in below example

```
INSERT `gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical_recent`
SELECT * 
FROM `gcp-sandbox.dailydev.historical` 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-07 23:00:00'
```